# How to generate table in the view using query in the controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem generating table using ci table.

I want to generate table using a query inside controller but the issue is the code...

```
echo $this->table->generate($query);
```

... from ci table, MUST BE inside the view.

I have a view called my_view.

I already made a query inside my controller.

my_controller.php

```
$data["all_jobs"] = $this->emp->get_all_filtered_candidate();
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: To generate table in the view using query in the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!

You have to prepare the table inside the controller and model then put it inside an variable array to carry over to your view. Example.

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{ 
   $this->load->model('your_model');
   $data['generated_code'] = $this->your_model->get_table(); 
   $this->load->view('your_view', $data);
}
```

**Model**

```
public function get_table()
{
   $query = $this->db->get('your_table');
   return $this->table->generate($query);
}
```

**View**

```
echo $generated_code;
```